# Finding factorial of a number using recursive call in MIPS programming

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

This is the C source code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    printf("The Factorial of 10 is %d\n", fact(10));
}

int fact(int n) {

    if (n < 1)
        return (1);
    else
        return (n * fact(n - 1));
}
```

I am converting a C Programming function to a MIPS, but when I run the MIPS program I am getting an error for the .ascii section.

```
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    subu    $sp,$sp,32  # Stack frame is 32 bytes long
    sw  $ra,20($sp)     # Save return address
    sw  $fp,16($sp)     # Save old frame pointer
    addiu   $fp,$sp,28  # Set up frame pointer

    li  $a0,10      # Put argument (10) in $a0
    jal     fact        # Call factorial function
    la  $a0,$LC     # Put format string in $a0
    move    $a1,$v0     # Move fact result to $a1
    jal     printf      # Call the print function

    lw  $ra,20($sp)     # Restore return address
    lw  $fp,16($sp)     # Restore frame pointer
    addiu   $sp,$sp,32  # Pop stack frame
    jr  $ra         # Return to caller
    
    .rdata
$LC:
    .ascii “The factorial of 10 is %d\n\000”

    .text
fact:
    subu    $sp,$sp,32  # Stack frame is 32 bytes long
    sw  $ra,20($sp)     # Save return address
    sw  $fp,16($sp)     # Save frame pointer
    addiu   $fp,$sp,28  # Set up frame pointer
    sw  $a0,0($fp)  # Save argument (n) to use for Recursive Call
    
    lw  $v0,0($fp)  # Load n
    bgtz    $v0,$L2     # Branch if n > 0
    li  $v0,1       # Return 1
    jr  $L1         # Jump to code to return
$L2:
    lw  $v1,0($fp)  # Load n
    subu    $v0,$v1,1   # Compute n - 1
    move    $a0,$v0     # Move value to $a0
    
    jal     fact        # Call factorial function
    lw  $v1,0($fp)  # Load n
    mul     $v0,$v0,$v1     # Compute fact(n-1) * n
    
$L1:                # Result is in $v0
    lw  $ra, 20($sp)    # Restore $ra
    lw  $fp, 16($sp)    # Restore $fp
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 32    # Pop stack
    jr  $ra         # Return to caller
```

It's giving me an error for the .ascii code section saying it shouldn't be in the .text:

> Error in ".ascii" directive cannot appear in text segment

It's also saying that:

> "$L1": operand is of incorrect type

Comment: `jr` takes a register.  Use `j L1` to do a normal direct jump.

Answer (score 2):

> It's giving me an error for the .ascii code section saying it shouldn't be in the .text:
>
> > Error in ".ascii" directive cannot appear in text segment"

I am going out on a limb here because I am not 100% sure what you are running this on, but some sims like MARS don't recognize the rdata segment. You can try using just `.data`.

Also, if you are on something like WinMIPS64, you may want to try placing the .data segment at the top of the code. I understand what you are doing is right in some environments and but doesn't work in others, so give it a whirl.

May I suggest you try these things separately, just in case.

Comment: Thank You for your help!, I did try putting the ascii all the way in the top using .data and it worked

Comment: Great! If my answer worked for you or was useful then, can you vote it up or accept it as an answer? ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers